# Wifi on Macbook vs Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, performance, unibody

How will you rate your wifi experience and over all experience between Macbook and Macbook pro?

How much of that good or bad is to do with Aluminium body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new 450 megabit per second (a.k.a. 3 spacial stream, 3x3) flavor of 802.11n on the Thunderbolt MacBook Pros is very nice, especially when combined with the latest AirPort Extreme and Time Capsule revisions from June that have modern 450 megabit per second 802.11n radios.

The plastic MacBooks and the MacBook Airs are still running the older 300 megabit per second flavor of 802.11n from 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I has an old Macbook (white one) and now i have an alu-Pro and haven't see any differences in the Wifi performance. But maybe someone others has more exact comparison.